# Fortran arrays argument

Tags: vba, fortran, vb6

I'm trying to convert a Fortran code to VBA, with very little knowledge of Fortran.

what does **P(I,1)** stand for? Or **P(1,J)**?  It is supposed to represent a scalar vector.

```
DO 25 J=1,NF
        DO 25 I=1,J
          CALL INPR(P(I,1),P(J,1),C(I,J),NF,NF,NF)
25        C(J,I)=C(I,J)

    C CALLED FROM MANY SUBROUTINES

       subroutine INPR (a, b, c, ia, ib, n)
c
c Caclulates the scalar product between two vectors
c
c   a   - input array
c   b   - input array
c   c   - output scalar product
c   ia  - input stride factor for array a
c   ib  - input stride factor for array b
c   n   - input number of elements
c
       dimension a(*), b(*)
       c = 0.0
       ipa = 1
       ipb = 1
       do 10 i = 1, n
           c = c + a(ipa) * b(ipb)
           ipa = ipa + ia
  10       ipb = ipb + ib
       return
       end
```

Comment: since C(J,I) is assingable and therefore an array, could not P be similarly an array defined earlier in the code?

Comment: `P(I,1)` could be an array element or a function reference. If it is an array element, as an argument it can have one of multiple effects. We cannot possibly tell what happens here without additional context. See [mre]. In general, one cannot look at three lines of Fortran code and know what they do.

Comment: @Cyrus: how can you be sure `C` is an array and not a function?

Comment: I guess `P` is a scalar and `C` is a matrix. Do you expect `p*transponse(p)=C(matrix)`?  I guess `INPR` is a function/subroutine. Could you please check, if it modifies the third argument and thus returns this value. Then both `P` values are inputs and the `C` is the output-matrix.   The `i` and `j` variables may loop trough the bottom half (or upper half) of the `C` matrix. In the line 25, the transposed entry of `C` is set.

Comment: I added the subroutine INPR to try clarifying a little bit

Comment: Dim p(). P is an array